# Expand variable and add results in single quotes

Tags: powershell, format

Silly question, but cant seem to figure it out.
How do I expand the content of a variable, and show the result in single quotes ?

```
    $Test = Hello
    Write-output $($Test)
```

I would like the result to be `'Hello'` including the quotes.

Comment: `Write-Output "'$($Test)'"` should yield the result you're after (note the double quotes to create a String and then the single quotes within that String). Also you need to enclose "Hello" in quotes `$Test = "Hello"` so that PowerShell interprets it as a String.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply :)

Comment: if you ALWAYS want the quotes to be there, you can save them as part of the $Var value. for instance, this `"'Hello'"` will print with the internal set of quotes. not that it is `<double quote><single quote>Hello<single quote><double quote>` and you can reverse them if you prefer to store the doubles instead of the singles. [*grin*]

Comment: Had to use it like this `$("'$Test'")` , but you pointed me in the right direction

Comment: I don't always want them to be single quotes, as the message is just for generating email and a log file, I use the variable for other useful stuff in my script, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With an **expandable string** ([string interpolation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375)):

```
# To embed *expressions*, additionally enclose in $(...); e.g., "'$($Test+1)'"
"'$Test'"
```

As a general aside: In order to merely *output* a value, there's no need for `Write-Output`, because PowerShell *implicitly* outputs expression / command results (that are neither captured nor redirected).

You can pass the expression above as-is as an argument to a command, there is *no* need for [`$(...)`, the subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#subexpression-operator--); sticking with the `Write-Output` sample command:

```
Write-Output "'$Test'"
```

Use expandable strings as a **convenient way of embedding the *default string representation*** of a variable value or expression result in a string.

---

With **`-f`, the string-formatting operator** (internally based on [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#Starting)):

```
"'{0}'" -f $Test  # {0} is a placeholder for the 1st RHS operand

# Enclose in (...) to pass the expression as an argument to a command:
Write-Output ("'{0}'" -f $Test)
```

The `-f` operator gives you **more control over the resulting string representation**, allowing you to perform operations such as padding and selecting the number of decimal places for floating-point numbers.

Note, however that this approach is **suitable only for *scalars***, not arrays (collections).

---

With **string concatenation** (`+`):

```
"'" + $Test + "'"

# Enclose in (...) to pass the expression as an argument to a command:
Write-Output ("'" + $Test + "'")
```

This a **more verbose alternative to string expansion** that makes the operation being performed more obvious.