# Expand array properties and add single quote

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.1

I'm working with Azure AD and I have imported a CSV file with some group name in it and I want to add single quote to the name properties of these group to query Azure AD but I can't seem to find any answer to my problem.

myfile.csv content:

```
name
Group Mémos - 1
Group Mémos - 2
```

I then need to add single quote to the item for when I query Azure AD

```
$group = import-csv c:\temp\myfile.csv

foraech ($item in $group)
{
Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq $("'$item.name'")" | select ObjectId
}
```

My problem is the content of $item is this:
'@{Name=Group Mémos - 1}.name'

but what I need is this:
'Group Mémos - 1'

How can I expand the name properties and add single quote to it?

I made a workaround by inserting the name property into another variable but I'm sure there is a way to do it that I don't understand...

```
$item2 = $item.Name
Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq $("'$item2'")" | select ObjectId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misplaced the [`$( )` subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#subexpression-operator--):

```bash
$group = Import-Csv c:\temp\myfile.csv
foreach ($item in $group) {
    Get-AzureADGroup -Filter "DisplayName eq '$($item.name)'" | Select-Object ObjectId
}
```

Comment: wow thanks, I got my basic sintax from this page and try to reproduce it with an expanded properties.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53241654/expand-variable-and-add-results-in-single-quotes